# Couchdb finder using CouchRest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb, couchrest, findby

I just want to know how can I build a find_all_by_action_and_author_id method in Rails with while using the couchdb. My Model looks like this:

```
class Activity < CouchRest::Model::Base
  property :action,    String
  property :author_id, String
end
```

if I try to build a View like that:

```
design do
  view :by_action_and_author_id
end
```

I dont know how to get the right result, I tried it with this:

```
Activity.by_action_and_author_id(:keys => [['action','foo'], ['author_id', '1']]).all
```

But the result is always a empty hash. What is the best way to do this? Any examples?

With PostgreSQL it would look like this

```
Activity.where(action: 'foo', author_id: '1').all
```

it cant be so complicated

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the generated couchdb-view! you can see which keys get emitted. there is no thing as a mapping there, so i think that `[['action','foo'], ['author_id', '1']]` should be just `['foo', '1']`.

i do not know for sure how couchrest-models handles views, but you can find more infos here: http://www.couchrest.info/model/view_objects.html

have a look at the tag-example.